# Font-size won't take up full screen width in Safari, Nextjs

Tags: css, next.js, react-hooks

I have a header component in my Nextjs application which takes up full screen width. It works in Chrome but not Safari.

The only time it actually refreshes and works in Safari and takes up full screen width is when opening inspect and close it. Why is that?

Here's some of my code:

```
const name = "Frontend Developer";

export default function Home() {
  const logoRef = useRef<HTMLHeadingElement>(null);

  const letters = Array.from(name);

  useEffect(() => {
    const resizeHandler = () => {
      if (logoRef.current) {
        const screenWidth = window.innerWidth - 10;
        const fontSize =
          screenWidth /
          (logoRef.current.offsetWidth /
            parseFloat(getComputedStyle(logoRef.current).fontSize));
        logoRef.current.style.fontSize = `${fontSize}px`;
      }
    };

    resizeHandler();

    window.addEventListener("resize", resizeHandler);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", resizeHandler);
  }, []);

  return (
    <main className={styles.header}>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <h1 ref={logoRef} className={styles.logo}>
          {letters.map((letter, index) => (
            <span key={index}>{letter}</span>
          ))}
        </h1>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```